# How can I add sections to my UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftbond

How can I add sections to my UITableViewCell with the Bond framework?

```
 self.viewModel.items.bind(to: self.tableView) { (item, indexPath, tableView) -> UITableViewCell in
                      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: ListCell.self),
                                                               for: indexPath) as! ListCell
                       cell.item = item[indexPath.row]
                      return cell
                  }.dispose(in: self.bag)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must write this class

```
class  CustomSection<Changeset: SectionedDataSourceChangeset>: TableViewBinderDataSource<Changeset>, UITableViewDelegate where Changeset.Collection == Array2D <String, ListItemViewModel> {

        @objc func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
            return changeset?.collection[sectionAt: section].metadata
        }
```

and in viewDidload of your ViewController you must call this function.

```
private func setupViewModel() {  
        let sectionBindingDatSource: CustomSection = CustomSection<TreeChangeset>{ (changeset, indexPath, tableView) -> UITableViewCell in
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: ListCell.self), for: indexPath) as! ListCell
            cell.item = changeset.sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]

            return cell
        }
        self.viewModel.sections.bind(to: self.tableView, using: sectionBindingDatSource)
    }
```

and if you want to override function of TableViewDataSourse and customize section you must set delegate

```
self.tableView.delegate = sectionBindingDatSource
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the source code,

if you want to override just a title, you should override this class and implement correspond logic for

```
open class TableViewBinderDataSource<Changeset: SectionedDataSourceChangeset>: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource
```

but if you want to implement totally custom view, this is much complicated. I don't think that this is possible for this library. the reason is that you should override `UITableViewDelegate`, but it is used in `public protocol ReactiveExtensions` that cannot be overridden.

Comment: This part of code that I share is work and this is right way in Bond framework